# Using the BasicTextField2 to use as a password entry with passwordVisualtransformation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following `BasicTextField2` and I would like to use it as a password entry. However, it doesn't seem to have a visualTransformation that will hide or show the password. Is they any way to do this without reverting to a `textField`

This my code with the visualTransformation commented out.

```
   BasicTextField2(
        modifier = modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester ?: FocusRequester())
            .background(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    listOf(Color.DarkGray, Color.Black)),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .border(width = 0.1.dp, color = Color.LightGray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
        value = currentValue,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.LightGray, fontSize = 16.sp),
        lineLimits = TextFieldLineLimits.SingleLine,
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None,
            autoCorrect = true,
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
       /* visualTransformation = if (isPasswordVisible) {
            VisualTransformation.None
        }
        else {
            PasswordVisualTransformation()
        },*/
        decorator = { textFieldDecorator ->
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier
            ) {
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                    modifier = Modifier
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = leadingIcon,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(8.dp)
                            .size(32.dp)
                    )

                    textFieldDecorator()
                }

                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                    modifier = Modifier

                ) {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        onVisibilityChange()
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                                visibilityIcon }
                            else { visibilityOffIcon
                            },
                            contentDescription = label
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Different from the old BasicTextField, the new BasicTextField2 has a flavor specifically for passwords, the `BasicSecureTextField`.

The developers describe it in a [blog entry](https://proandroiddev.com/basictextfield2-a-textfield-of-dreams-2-2-fdc7fbbf9ffb#e689) as follows:

> Having BasicSecureTextField as a separate composable is very powerful. It allows the team to optimise for security under the hood, making sure the field content is not persisted in memory more than it should, avoiding things like memory spoofing. It comes with predefined UI with mask and textObfuscationModes, and also explicit behaviours that come with it, for instance the text toolbar modifications (you cannot cut or copy the contents of a password field).

It can be used like this:

```
// the new BasicTextField2 works best with a TextFieldState instead of a String
val password = rememberTextFieldState("password")

BasicSecureTextField(
    state = password,
    modifier = Modifier.border(width = 0.1.dp, color = Color.LightGray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
    textObfuscationMode = TextObfuscationMode.RevealLastTyped,
)
```

As already mentioned, some configurations are already built in like the appropriate `KeyboardOptions`, `InputTransformation` and context menu options (like preventing copying from the text field).